# Jenkins build error with code coverage

Tags: jenkins, build, code-coverage

I have an error that appears when I try to run my Codeception tests with the code coverage.
The tests are correctly executed without the code coverage on the server when I launch them in the console.

Here is the error returned on Jenkins :

```
BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/vaco-hook-arthur/build.xml:110: exec returned: 139
```

When I launch Codeception directly on my jenkins server with
`--colors --coverage --coverage-html --coverage-xml --html --xml`, the following error appears :

```
Segmentation fault
```

Any advice ?